# Arrays of different types

Tags: java

Is it possible to have an array that contains two different types of data? I want to have an array that contains a double and also a string. I attempted:

```
ArrayList<double><String> array;
```

But that didn't work.

Sorry for the silly question, but it has been a while since I have used something like this.. Can you refresh my memory on how would I declare and populate such an array?

And then to take it a step further, I would like to sort the array by the double if possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No, this is not possible. What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe we can help you come up with a workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Firstly, it's worth being clear about the difference between an array and an `ArrayList` - they're not the same thing at all.

However, in either case you can't do what you want. The closest you can probably come is declaring your own type. (EDIT: My original code had a double *or* a string... I've now changed it to be a double *and* a string. Let me know if this change *isn't* what you had in mind.)

```
public final class DoubleAndString
{
    private final String stringValue;
    private final double doubleValue;

    public DoubleAndString(String stringValue, double doubleValue)
    {
        this.stringValue = stringValue;
        this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
    }

    public String getString()
    {
        return stringValue;
    }

    public String getDouble()
    {
        return doubleValue;
    }
}
```

Then create an `ArrayList<DoubleAndString>` or a `DoubleAndString[]`.

Now, this feels somewhat vanilla at the moment - presumably the double and string values actually have a greater meaning - a name and a score, for example. If so, encapsulate that in a type which describes the pairing more appropriately.

As for ordering - you *could* make `DoubleAndString` implement `Comparable<DoubleAndString>` - but unless that's the *only* natural ordering which makes sense, I'd write a `Comparator<DoubleAndString>`:

```
public class DoubleComparator implements Comparator<DoubleAndString>
{
    public int compare(DoubleAndString ds1, DoubleAndString ds2)
    {
        return Double.compare(ds1.getDouble(), ds2.getDouble());
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Collections.sort` to sort an `ArrayList<DoubleAndString>` or `Arrays.sort` to sort an array.

Comment: +1, beat'd.  That was going to be my suggestion and custom data type.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ArrayList<Object>` and you can then use anything you'd like. Encapsulate the `double` in a `Double` object and when you retrieve the object use `instanceof` to check if it's really a `double` or a `String`.

I must say, it's unlikely this 'design' would win you any awards. Is it possible to rethink the solution you're considering for your problem, and see if you could do with a different kind of approach?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a Map. Since you wish to sort the Map, a TreeMap may be optimal.

```
Map<Double, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
```

Maps are associative. Each double has an associated string. If you want multiple strings per double, you can use a

```
Map<Double, ArrayList<String>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might already know this, but it is not certainly not a good idea to store different types in a list. By definition an array is a collection of similar objects and stuffing all kinds in it makes things fuzzy. So really you would rather have a separate type to hold these different values.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to have an array with an arbitrary number of elements, then you simply need to use a type that is a common ancestor to both. In this case, that would be Object (since String and Double both inherit from Object). This will require you to check the types, though, when you retrieve or use them.

If you are using a fixed number of multiple different types, then what you really want is a "tuple". However, Java currently does not have an implementation of tuple available. For two items:

```
public class Pair<T1,T2>
{
    public Pair(){
          this(null,null);
    }

    public Pair(T1 x1){
          this(x1,null);
    }

    public Pair(T1 x1, T2 x2){
         _x1 = x1;
         _x2 = x2;
    }

    public T1 getFirst(){
        return _x1;
    }

    public T1 getSecond(){
        return _x2;
    }

    private T1 _x1;
    private T2 _x2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `ArrayList<object> arraylist` and then you can put anything in it, but that may not be what you want.

Then, to sort you would just use your own comparator but, as theatrus mentioned, are these two values supposed to be connected, or do you have a single-dimension array with two different data types?

Answer (score 2):

An ArrayList by definition only contains one object per position.  You could do something like this:

```
List<MyTuple> list = new ArrayList<MyTuple>();

public static class MyTuple implements Comparable<MyTuple> {

    private Double doubleValue;
    private String stringValue;

    //getters and setters

    public int compareTo(MyTuple tuple) {
        return doubleValue.compareTo(tuple.getDoubleValue());
    }
}
```

You can then use the Collections.sort() method to sort it by the Doubles.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do?

If it is not a key value mapping, you should create a new class for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the Number base class.

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Number>(); 
list.add(new Integer(3)); 
list.add(new Double(5.2));
```

You may interpret the numbers as strings, using NumberFormat:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
String s = formatter.format(list.get(0));
```

Though this may not be what you want, you are a bit short on details about your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

if you are basically not trying to do any comparisons/sorting on the ArrayList then you could create something as below:

List list = new ArrayList();

otherwise.. Jon Skeet's answer was best approach.