# Pass an Array of many types to an Oracle Procedure in Java

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

Is there any way to pass an array of various types in java to a oracle procedure?

For example:
I have to call the oracle procedure SYS.PACK_DID3530 passing the following parameters: (In the link below)

The following link contains an image of the structure. I can't post an image in this post because i'm a new user.
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/563630_585790028112205_1641543883_n.jpg

I've looked at some examples that use an array of a specific type.

Comment: Just refer this link.It might be useful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/2815672/2032549

Comment: What is the signature of your PL/SQL procedure? Why is this procedure in the `SYS` schema?

Comment: Hy Vincent, i dont know the signature, just recieved the documentation to implement that way. And Unaware of the reason for the procedure is in SYS schema